# Terraform custom provider override diffing on encrypted values

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider

First time I'm creating a custom provider so I'm sorry if this is a silly question to ask.

One of the resources is taking a Kubernetes secret and encrypting it as a sealed secret then pushing it to a Git repository.

I have noticed an issue with the Terraform diffing of this value. In the  `ReadContext` func I'm grabbing the requested resource from Git and then setting the value using the `Set` func from `ResourceData`. The problem is that this value is encrypted in Git and comparing it with the current value in the `main.tf` will always trigger an update since that value is in cleartext.

I have tried using the `CustomizeDiff` in the `schema.Resource`, but I have not been able to working the way I want it to.

One way to solve this is to override the Terraform diffing by encrypting the value in `main.tf` and comparing it with the value stored in Git.

Is this possible, or have I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: Could you decrypt the value within the resource schema?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I could in theory, but I'm not sure how optimal that is considering the security. Isn't it considered bad practice to store sensitive information in the Terraform state?

Comment: In situations like this, you would normally want to mark the argument value as sensitive in the provider. This is possible as long as you are using the plugin sdk v2. The state and `stdout` behavior for sensitive inputs, outputs, and argument values depends on the version of Terraform.

Comment: To better understand your issue, could you please provide an example of resource configuration and a snippet of how you've used `CustomizeDiff` that did not work for you?